# Sending multiple data in Laravel Pipeline

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to send multiple data when using laravel Pipeline ? I mean i would like to send `$user` and `$thread` instance:

```php
app(Pipeline::class)
    ->send($user, $thread)
    ->through([
        CustomFilter::class
    ])
    ->then(...);
```

But the `send` method only accept one argument and i unable to receive `$thread` in `handle` method on `CustomFilter` class

Comment: have you considered passing $user, $thread in array and unpacking them at your filter

Comment: Sure, But there are 12 other filter classes and it is annoying to do this on every places

Comment: well it doesn't seem like you have any other choice